Do not use dependency from conda
I have installed ds9 to view astronomical FITS images
Also I use a conda distribution for python
Now every time I open ds9 it will say:
$ ds9
ds9: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.74: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

which I found is that:
ds9 use icu from my conda (not from my system), and while my Archlinux has icu-75, the icu on conda-forge is still icu-73
https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/icu
How to make ds9 use system libicui18n but not conda's?
If I comment out the conda init paragraph in my .bashrc and rebuild ds9, it will be good, but I don't want to rebuild ds9 every time icu update.
